# Delete /data/data folder

Tags: android

My application is a system application. What I need is to perform clean data for all other applications. As far as I know, data for all application store in /data/data. Is there any way to remove all folders/files in /data/data programatically?

I know how to do that from adb:

```
adb shell
# rm -r /data/data
```

And this is how I'm trying to do it in the code:

```
Process process;
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes("mount -o remount,rw -t rfs /dev/stl5 /data; \n");
        os.writeBytes("rm -r /data/data; \n");
        os.writeBytes("mount -o remount,ro -t rfs /dev/stl5 /data; \n");

        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Please stop.  You have no idea what you are doing and so should not be attempting with system level tasks.

Comment: Could you advice something that is more sensible? How can I clean data for all applications? I've my own box running under Android. There are several application on it (just my own, there are no any gallery or player). What I need - clean all data.

Comment: No, you are in way over your head, and helping you over this momentary hurdle will only increase the chances of making a bigger and more dangerous mess of things.  You need to invest some serious time in understanding android before you break it's security model.

Comment: Maybe you are right. Can you tell me at least: Is it possible? And what could happen if I find the way how to do that? In one sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, your app *can't* be a system application, unless you've rooted your phone. For a non-rooted phone, you don't have access to the data of other apps unless they wrote the data to a public area and made it world-writeable. Even so, your app should refrain from touching anything that it doesn't own.

What happens if you do this in adb? You can cause other apps to stop working correctly.

However, you're asking the programming equivalent of "what happens if I stick my fingers in a lamp socket?" The sensible among us would conclude that we have no obligation to answer you, on the off chance that you'll actually go off and do it.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea if that works, but even if it did, your program would certainly need root (su / superuser) to be able to mess with that location.